# Calibre: what's a good format to convert to, in order to simplify cut and paste of code samples?

Tags: calibre

Using Calibre, I'd like to convert a programming book, which I've purchased, from Kindle format to a format better suited to copy code samples into my text editor.  Copying from Kindle works, but it mangles the code really badly.

This is on a Mac.  I am guessing **rtf** or maybe even **docx**.  **pdf** sounds like I would again end up with potentially painful copy/paste hurdles.

Plain **txt**?  I didn't see **markdown**.

One problem I am seeing is that **txt**,**rtf** conversion messes up lines:

from

`this is line 1
line2`

to

`1 this is line 1 2 line2`

which my was my Kindle copy issue in the first place.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik   you're right, much better.  if you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool I found to open .MOBI documents is the [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) file viewer itself. At least on the documents I've tried, plain text is formatted correctly when copied and pasted from the E-book viewer into LibreOffice Writer.

[Sumatra](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) and some other viewers can open that format, but copy-and-paste from Calibre works well.